# How to define a bijection from the set $\mathfrak C$ of Dedekind cuts to $\mathcal{P}(\Bbb Q)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This question arises when I tried to prove $|\mathcal{P}(\Bbb N)|=|\Bbb R|$ without appealing to the decimal representation of real numbers (with which I'm not familiar).

---

**My attempt:**

Let $\mathfrak C$ be the set of Dedekind cuts of $(\Bbb Q,<)$.

For all $c\in \mathfrak C:c=(A,B)$ where $A\cap B=\emptyset$ and $A\cup B=\Bbb Q$.

We define a mapping $f:\mathfrak C \to \mathcal{P}(\Bbb Q)$  by $f(c)=A$ for all $c=(A,B)\in \mathfrak C$. Then $f$ is injective.

---

> I'm stuck at proving $f$ is surjective. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Because it's not surjective. Why would it be? What would be the cut mapped to $\varnothing$? Or to $\Bbb N$?

Comment: Thank you @AsafKaragila! I will try to define another bijection.

Comment: Bijections are overrated. Use the Cantor–Bernstein theorem.

Comment: Hi @AsafKaragila! Is it possible to construct such an explicit bijection or we're only able to prove its existence?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, you can work out a bijection by hand. But it's ***reallllly*** long, tedious, and complicated. And not something you should spend time on at this point of time. This is more of a fun after lunch exercise for when you have gained enough mathematical experience to do these things quicker.

Comment: Thank you so much @AsafKaragila! I got your point :)

Comment: To add to @Asaf 's comment: If you can construct the injections that you input into the Cantor-Bernstein theorem, the bijection you get out (of its proof) is constructible as well. It has a relatively simple definition that only depends on the input injections. That's pretty explicit in my book.